# ADO.Net Entity framework object navigation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using ADO.Net Entity Framework and C# to retreive the languages of a destination using this:

```
var list =
   from dd in guiaContext.DestinationDetail
   where dd.id_destination == destinationID
   select dd;
```

But when I access language in a foreach:

```
foreach (DestinationDetail detail in list)
   languagesList.Add(detail.Language.ds_language);
```

detail.Language is null. Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there 2 tables : destination and language ?
Is there a foreign key relationshipt between the destination and language table ?

That would help in commenting on the above problem of language being null.

By default EF does not retrieve the referenced table (lazy loading).

Try this :

var list =   from dd in guiaContext.DestinationDetail   Include("Language") where dd.id_destination == destinationID   select dd;

Look at the following link on eager loading in Entity Framework:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx